# Windows Update not working

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

"There were problems installing some updates, but we'll try again later.  ..... Error 0x80070057"

That error code is so generic, it didn't get me to a solution.  I spent a couple of days on this and solved it eventually and will provide the solution I found later in case it helps anyone else.

What I tried were the following steps:

1. Created a system restore point for later recovery if needed.
2. System disk checked: Your drive was successfully scanned.  Windows successfully scanned the drive. No errors were found.
3. Based on https://support.microsoft.com/en-hk/help/4027322/windows-update-troubleshooter - Ran the troubleshooter: "Troubleshooting couldn't identify the problem."
4. Attempted to Install Diagnostic Data Viewer; "Error"
   Clicked 'See details'
   "Something unexpected happened
   Reporting this problem will help us understand it better. You can wait for a while and try again or restart your device.  That may help. 
   Code: 0x80070057"  [Yep, the very one I'm trying to fix.]
5. Working from https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4089834/windows-10-troubleshoot-problems-updating?ocid=20SMC10164Windows10

   - My C: drive has 296GB free
   - Restarting hasn't helped. I've had this problem for days and the PC has been restarted multiple times.
   - Retried checking for Updates in Settings: Same errors.
   - Removed non-essential devices, tried Windows Update again: Same error reports as listed above.
   - Updated drivers, retried checking for Updates in Settings: Same errors.
   - Device Manager shows no yellow triangles/exclamation marks

In cmd as admin, did:

```
net stop bits
```

The Background Intelligent Transfer Service service is stopping..

The Background Intelligent Transfer Service service was stopped successfully.

```
ren %systemroot%\softwaredistribution softwaredistribution.bak2

ren %systemroot%\system32\catroot2 catroot2.bak2
```

Access is denied.

[Took ownership of catroot2, added my user, gave my user Full control - this is probably not recommended, and didn't work anyway]

```
ren %systemroot%\system32\catroot2 catroot2.bak2
```

The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

[Tried to unlock it with IOBit Unlocker: BSOD, restarted in Safe Mode, renamed catroot2 as catroot2.bak, restarted normally]

In cmd as admin, did:

```
net start bits
```

The requested service has already been started.  More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2182.

```
net start wuauserv
```

The requested service has already been started.  More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2182.

Restarted machine

Tried Windows update: it gave the above 3 error messages as before.

Uninstalled Avast Free Antivirus.

Tried Windows update: As before, but I saw that while trying it did download and install an update to Windows Defender.

Reinstalled Avast.

Tried Windows update: Error as before.

Performed a clean boot in accordance with https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929135/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows

This involves stopping all non-MS services and all startup software

Windows update worked.

Restored from the system restore point. Everything except Windows Update working again.

Now I have to find out which startup item or service is causing the problem.  There are many, but at least I have a path to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

After trying various startup and service items, I eventually found that the problem was the Cybereason RansomFree service.  This app has not been supported since January 2019, but I carried on using it.

After uninstalling it, Windows Update works on both of my Win 10 PCs.